# Kibana 7.13.4 is not running in windows 10

Tags: elasticsearch, version, kibana

Am using Elastic Search 7.13.4 and Kibana 7.13.5 for my work. In windows 10 am running `elasticsearch.bat` file given in bin folder and it running fine. In my browser `http://localhost:9200/` i see its running without any error.

And when I try to run `kibana.bat` file in bin folder of kibana, it exits without any info or error. At `http://localhost:5601/`, i dont se any logs.  I ran `kibana.bat` as administrator also, but all the batch files in bin folder exits within a second.  Because of this I started using Elastic Search and Kibana 5.6.5 version and its working fine.

Issue is only with 7.13.4 version. Should I do any extra configuration for this version?

Here is the kibana.yml file link
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml

Comment: Kibana 7.13.5 has not been released yet. Maybe you can post your kibana.yml configuration file?

Comment: @Val How to upload file here ?

Comment: You have the option to copy/paste it into your question, otherwise you can [gist it](https://gist.github.com/)

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml

Comment: What do you mean? it's the default file without any modification?

Comment: Yes, am using as it is without any modification in any file of kibana

Comment: Can you run kibana.bat from the command line instead of double clicking on it? What output do you get?

Comment: When i run `kibana.bat` in command promt in winwdows, then i see below error.  `FATAL  Error: Cannot find module './persistence_defense_evasion_hidden_launch_agent_deamon_logonitem_process.json'
Require stack:`

Comment: Can you update your question with the full output please?